# Export docx to pdf with vba

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word

I would like to export docx file to pdf file from excel vba.
Document file.docx is opened correctly.
However, an error occurred while calling the method `ExportAsFixedFormat`: **Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument**.
I think arguments are ok.

Next little bug: `ActiveDocument.Path` does not work. There is an error "Run-time error '424': Object required" Therefore I used `WordApp.Documents(myFileName).ExportAsFixedFormat` instead `ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat`.

This code is executed from file Macro.xlsm. I use Microsoft Office 2021.

[Method exportasfixedformat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat)

```
Dim fileNameDoc As String
Dim fileNamePdf As String
Dim WordApp

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
FileNameDoc = "D:\rd\file.docx"

WordApp.Documents.Open FileNameDoc
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.Documents(FileNameDoc).Activate ' <- activation doesn't work

fileNamePdf = "D:\rd\file.pdf"
'fileNamePdf = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & "file.pdf" 

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat
' here is error: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument
WordApp.Documents(myFileName).ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=fileNamePdf, _
                                                             ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                                                             OpenAfterExport:=False, _
                                                             OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
                                                             Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
                                                             Item:=wdExportDocumentWithMarkup, _
                                                             IncludeDocProps:=False, _
                                                             CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
                                                             BitmapMissingFonts:=True

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.close(method)'
WordApp.Documents(myFileName).Close _
'ActiveDocument.Close _ 
    SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, _ 
    OriginalFormat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat
```

Any idea for a solution?

Comment: To get full path of file, use the format `ActiveDocument.Path & "\" &
 ActiveDocument.Name`. Try running with only the required arguments for `.ExportAsFixedFormat`.

Comment: Please, try `fileNamePdf = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & "file.pdf"`. Running Word **automation**, the code does not know what `ActiveDocument` is. You need to fully qualify it.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Yes, I only remarked Office 2021. Thanks! Deleted the sentence in discussion...

Comment: ```WordDoc.Path``` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you have used is for Word and uses a lot of Word constants e.g. `wdExportFormatPDF`, `wdExportOptimizeForPrint`, `wdExportDocumentWithMarkup`, `wdExportCreateNoBookmarks`, `wdSaveChanges`, `wdOriginalDocumentFormat`. Excel does not understand what these are.

You have two options. The best option is to set a reference to the Word library. In the Visual Basic Editor select References from the Tools menu. In the resulting dialog page down (approx 16 times) until you see the entry for the Microsoft Word Object library and check the box next to it.

[image]

Your other option is to create constants in your code for each Word constant you want to use. You'll need to use the object browser in Word, or the online help, to look up the values.

Similarly, Excel does not understand `ActiveDocument`. You need to prefix any Word objects you wish to use with `WordApp`. However, it would be better if you used a variable to point to the document you open:

```
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileNameDoc)
```

You can then use the `WordDoc` variable instead of `ActiveDocument`

```
Dim fileNameDoc As String
Dim fileNamePdf As String
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
fileNameDoc = "D:\rd\file.docx"

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(fileNameDoc)
WordApp.Visible = True

fileNamePdf = WordDoc.Path & "\" & "file.pdf"

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat
WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=fileNamePdf, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
    OpenAfterExport:=False, _
    OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
    Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentWithMarkup, _
    IncludeDocProps:=False, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.close(method)'
WordDoc.Close _
 SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, _
 OriginalFormat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat
```

Comment: I added Word Library in References. Now it works. Thank you. And which method would be better to use, ```WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat``` or ```WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat2```? Both work.

Comment: As both are current just use whichever works for you. `WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat2` includes an additional parameter, `OptimizeForImageQuality`. I’m not aware of any fundamental difference besides that.